# jquery animation call back function in the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a continues animation for an element.
i have created a class and used a j query animate method as in the following

```
class street {
    constructor(streetLength){
        this.lineLength=0;
        this.space=0;
        this.speed=4;
        this.streetLength=streetLength;
    }
    moveLine(element){
        $(element).animate({top:'+=1px'},100,function(){
            console.log('animating');
            this.moveLine(element);
        }); 
    }
}
```

When Im using the moveLine(element) function in the call back again for continues animation ,
 I'm getting an error message saying that 'moveline is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it but maybe is something wrong with "this" context, try this one:

```
class street {
    constructor(streetLength){
        this.lineLength=0;
        this.space=0;
        this.speed=4;
        this.streetLength=streetLength;
    }
    moveLine(element){
        $this = this;
        $(element).animate({top:'+=1px'},100,function(){
            console.log('animating');
            $this.moveLine(element);
        }); 
    }
}
```